# How to block console from returning with WPF application attached to console while App is still running

Tags: c#, wpf, console-application

I have the following code in WPF entry point

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
    private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Args.Length == 0)
        {
            // Launch GUI and pass arguments in case you want to use them.
            base.OnStartup(e);
            new MainWindow().ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            //Do command line stuff
            if (e.Args.Contains("-i"))
            {
                // redirect console output to parent process;
                // must be before any calls to Console.WriteLine()
                AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
                var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
                stopWatch.Reset();
                stopWatch.Start();

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
                stopWatch.Stop();
                var ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                var elapsedTime = $"{ts.Hours:00}:{ts.Minutes:00}:{ts.Seconds:00}.{ts.Milliseconds / 10:00}";
                Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);               
            }
            else
            {
                AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect arguments");
            }
        }

        Shutdown();
    }
}
```

The prompt returns immediately as though my app runs in the background.

[image]

**I would expect the app to block the console from being returned until the process is completed.**

Comment: What's a question again?

Comment: Fair enough, added more info. :-)

Comment: From your posted code, I can't see how the app would "run in the background". If there are command line arguments, it runs that `for` loop and then `Shutdown()`, it doesn't start the main window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AttachConsole` re-uses the existing console use `AllocConsole()` instead. This will block the console unless the parent process is running and will close the console as soon as the program finishes execution.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool AllocConsole();
```